# If city life is urban, what do you call living in a forest?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I know that rural relates to living in the countryside, and urban and suburban refer to living in cities, towns or residential areas. But some places, like in upstate New York, have dense trees and woodland. A forest, basically. 
What do you call that?

Urban life and (required word) life?

Comment: While *arboreal* usually suggests living *in* trees, it can be used to mean [living *among* trees](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/arboreal).

Comment: Urban and forested are not exclusive.  The city I live in is in a forest.  If you don't weed you get trees.  Historically this wasn't the case but nowadays we burn more oil than wood to keep warm.  So wild tree's are back in many developed areas.

Comment: "woodland life".

Comment: @CandiedOrange Manhattan would fit your description....those pesky seedlings in the concrete cracks evoke wolves hunting deer among stately trees, rushing streams, sylvan glades....

Comment: Endorian........?

Comment: Hardly anyone these days actually lives in the forest. Rural and rustic locations are probably the closest in modern times.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try **[sylvan](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20sylvan&oq=define%20sylvan&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3814j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)** from the Latin *silva*, a wood.

From *[Wingless Flights: Appalachian Women in Fiction](https://books.google.com/books?id=vKHDKyW-1akC&pg=PA21&dq=%22sylvan%20life%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAn-bb8tbJAhXLej4KHdrgBvkQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=%22sylvan%20life%22&f=false)* by Danny Miller

> Likewise, much of Frost's language in this article emphasizes the golden age simplicity and wholesomeness of the Appalachian region. He speaks of his "**sylvan** hosts" on his visits to the mountaineers and of their "**sylvan** life".

Comment: Nice catch. Very poetic though.

Comment: Yes ... "sylvan" does sound rather poetic (indeed flowery) ... perhaps "woodsy" or "forested" are a bit more down to earth, so to speak. But as others have noted, rural itself covers a lot of different terrain.

Comment: Sometimes spelled [silvan](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/silvan).

Comment: Especially if you're from Pennsilvania.

Comment: As used in the 'Sylvanian family' toys, though I'm not sure about the doubled ending.

Comment: Was it poetic before Keats used it in Grecian Urn?

Comment: @WilsonofGordon Most definitely.  Most, but not all, of the *OED*'s cites for *sylvan* are from works of poetry, going back to the 1500s.

Comment: Usually I just pronounce an anathema on the driveby downvoter, a plague upon this site, for the discourtesy or the potential for misleading readers (or both). But only the first applies here, leaving me to wonder what could possibly be wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 23):

To classify it in the range that includes urban and suburban, a forested area beyond those sections would still be classified as **rural**.

Note that you could have a densely wooded area within the boundaries of an otherwise built up city. It might be considered an urban forest. You could also have a totally denuded area, far from any city (such as a strip mine) which would be considered rural.

So, urban vs. suburban vs. rural basically indicates the locality's population density, rather than the specific amount of natural vegetation.

EDIT — I also like @deadrat's answer of "sylvan", but wanted to show a horrible example of how that word is often misappropriated by development marketers, in places that are clearly suburban:
[image]

Comment: I think OP has a misunderstanding of the word *rural* which somehow makes them think it does not apply to forested areas. Many, if not most, places in the U.S. that are considered *rural* are heavily forested. I have lived in forested areas my entire life (a large chunk of my life even in a literal hand-built log cabin, and currently on the edge of an actual United States National Forest) and have always heard the term *rural* used to describe such areas. **rural** is the answer.

Comment: I'm not convinced population density has much to do with it. An abandoned city is still an urban setting, for example. Development might be a more accurate basis for "urbanness".

Comment: @talrnu You make a good point, but there are exceptions, for example, a highly developed military installation in a rural area. Abandoned cities are anomalies — they might be urban settings, but I don't know if you'd still call it urban if people no longer live there.

Comment: If it's really far away from cities it's definitely **Rural**, if not so much it's **Suburban**, if it's really close to it, it's **Urban** **Rural** areas are usually related to the agricultural economy/life style due to their distance from cities which make people who live in rural areas produce their own food in some cases, if it's not the case, let's say it's a house in the mountains you can call it **remote** which is a way broader term.

Comment: "Woods woods" nice

Answer (score 1):

"Woodland" is a clear and simple adjective without baggage.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw in "**bucolic**".

> relating to the pleasant aspects of the countryside and country life.

---

Example usage from Seabiscuit: An American Legend:

> Even in the bucolic surroundings of Columbia, Seabiscuit could not escape the carnival atmosphere.

Answer (score 0):

The word "[rustic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rustic?s=t)" may be useful here, it's less poetic than "sylvan".

> "of, relating to, or living in the country, as distinguished from towns or cities"

*Definition from dictionary.reference.com*

Comment: Rustic does not mean forested.  A sylvan setting may be rustic, but a rustic setting is not necessarily sylvan.

Comment: Hi @Clifton, welcome to ELU. Answers are generally better with definitions, and a reference/link to where you got that definition. I've suggested an edit to achieve this for this post.