# If living in the countryside is rural, what do you call living by the sea?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call living by the beach?

Living in the countryside is a rural lifestyle.

Living in a city is an urban lifestyle.

Living by the sea is a * lifestyle?

Comment: *Maritime living* is a possibility, but it could include living AT sea. Some countries e.g. France talk of their *maritime provinces*. I suppose one could speak of the *maritime counties* of Britain, or the *maritime states of the USA i.e. those bordering the sea.

Comment: simply *seaside lifestyle* ?

Comment: Living *at* sea is of course *Nautical*

Comment: Webster's Unabridged 1913 defines "paralian" (n.) as "one who lives by the sea", so maybe that's worth exploring for an adjectival variant?
http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Paralian

Comment: Never heard `Paralian`before - nice one. It makes 'littoral' seem positively colloquial, with paralian being a complete no show on google ngram.

Comment: The OP starts with a confused premise.  'Urban' is often and sensibly contrasted with 'rural.  Neither word describes the character of a geograhic location. '*Living in the countryside*...' is what all of us living on land are doing!

Comment: @Ben- nautical is having to do with ships, sailors and navigation not living by the seaside.

Comment: It's good to note that the two are not mutually exclusive.  A seaside village can still be characterized as a rural setting.

Comment: Related: [What's the category name of “city” and “rural”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75103/whats-the-category-name-of-city-and-rural) (and of course your previous question [If city life is urban, what do you call living in a forest?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293474/if-city-life-is-urban-what-do-you-call-living-in-a-forest))

Comment: @Graffito Can you put that as an answer?

Comment: @mattdm - done!

Comment: *Paralian* is a nice new word to me too! A borrowing from Greek, interestingly explained in the OED as "...a member of a people living on the coast of Attica (usually as plural, Παράλιοι ), use as noun of masculine singular of παράλιος (adjective) *by the sea, **maritime***"!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You might also consider ***coastal***:

Defined by [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coastal)

> *adj*. pertaining to or bordering on a coast.

Here's a magazine dedicated to it:

[***Coastal Living***](http://www.coastalliving.com/)

Comment: *Coastal* living applies also to living by a lake. *Seaside* living is unambiguous.

Comment: *Coastal* is both *lakeside* and *seaside*, as is also *littoral*.

Comment: @Drew I'd only consider describing a lakeside home as *coastal* if it was on a very large lake on par with a sea, especially as a "coast" is "the land along or near a sea or ocean", according to MW at least.

Comment: In the UK, where lakes are relatively small, we say 'lake-side'.  But I imagine that for the larger lakes of the world - Superior, Victoria, Baikal - using 'coastal' would be common. So, to describe '*living by the sea'*  unambiguously I'd say (like @Drew) '*seaside*' or '*maritime*'.

Comment: And in Australia, where the lakes are small but the sea-coast is very large, "coast" is almost exclusively for the sea (likewise "coastal"). To me, lakes have *shores*, not coasts. Like @Dan, I would say "lakeside" (no hyphen for me, though). But "seaside" is also common, and salespeople would say "beachside" if there's even a hint of beach on the stretch of coast in question.

Comment: In US Chicago calls it Lakeside by Lake Michigan which is the third largest Great Lake. Coastal regions also applies to West and East Coast - so where is Coastal used for a lake?

Comment: @Mark - how would someone in Chicago say they were going North to Milwaukee -'up lakeside to Milwaukee', 'up the coast to Milwaukee'...?

Answer (score 14):

The word you want is [littoral](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/littoral):

> Of or on a shore, especially a seashore: a littoral property; the littoral biogeographic zone.

---

UPDATE:  I'd actually like express appreciation to the down-voters and to @MadHackers counter-answer for calling me out on this.  It seems I don't even follow [my own advice](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7435/13804).  I had thought littoral was a more common word than others do- certainly not in everyday conversation, but more in news reports and some TV documentaries.  Then again, the shows I watch and the magazines I read are not exactly mainstream.

Comment: This is extremely rare when coupled with 'house' etc in British English at least. it occurs most frequently in specialised registers.

Comment: This seems to be a case of technically correct but infrequently used in regular talk. When we see a magazine called "Littoral Living"...

Comment: I'd expect "littoral" to refer to the house actually being on the beach, whereas I suspect the questioner has a wider strip of land in mind when talking about people living "by the sea". That magazine is for a pretty niche market regardless whether or not it's the word people would actually use where it's applicable.

Comment: +1 I'm familiar with the word, but I wasn't until I became acquainted with [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littoral_combat_ship)

Answer (score 11):

If you're comparing it to rural, it will still be called either rural, suburban or urban, depending on the area.

A sparsely populated seaside location far from a city center, will be considered rural. An oceanfront condo in a large port city will be urban.

I live near the beach, but also within walking distance of a rapid transit station. It's essentially suburban.

Comment: Indeed!  A very good point.

Answer (score 5):

Or possibly *maritime* -

Of a place: bordering the sea. Of a person: living near or by the sea. (OED)

Comment: I think "maritime" brings to mind the sea itself and so "maritime living" might more likely be living on a ship than living by the sea. Just my feeling, though.

Answer (score 4):

simply **seaside lifestyle**.

Excerpt of [Coast of Dreams](https://books.google.fr/books?id=fw5N5qg5BHQC&pg=PA7&dq=%22seaside%20lifestyle%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipzPP19u3JAhVCvBoKHT7PA2w4ChDoAQhJMAY#v=onepage&q=%22seaside%20lifestyle%22&f=false) by Kevin Starr:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Australian English, and the person has deliberately moved from a large urban city to a less populated coastal area, you may call them a [seachanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seachange_(demography)), named after the TV series [SeaChange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaChange) which involved this scenario.

If they moved from a large urban city to a non-coastal area, you can call them a "treechanger" instead.

Comment: I don't know whether *SeaChange* is the source of the term, though it certainly popularised it. I don't think the title of the show would've made sense if "a sea-change" wasn't already a comprehensible phrase. (Your Wikipedia link identifies Shakespeare as the source of the term, though I doubt his Ariel was singing about moving to a coastal town.) Of course, now that it *is* popular, we have the appalling "tree-change" for moving out to the bush...